# console.log shows nothing in FF add-on builder

Tags: javascript, firefox, console, builder, add-on

I have following problem: No log pessage shows me in every console (builder's console absolutely useless - nothing happened at all when I click, built-in FF console shows every info about installing, uninstalling etc, Firebug shows nothing).

I used console.log(), console.error() without success.
On about:config page is every logLevel's set to 'all' and devtools.errorconsole.enabled is also true.

Please help me, I'm desperate :-(

Thank you.

Kamil

PS: log window is bellow. There are 3 css errors (by default 'cause I don't include any css file - it's something about expected declarations and skipped to next declaration). Program code is simple console.log('test') or console.error('test') inside or outside exports.main = function().

```
17:34:52.086 GET https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/get_latest_revision_number/1127553/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 207ms]
17:34:52.086 GET https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/check_latest_dependencies/1835317/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 215ms]
17:34:52.088 POST https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/xpi/prepare_test/1835317/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 805ms]
17:34:52.862 "XPI delayed ... try to load every 2 seconds" ide-min.js:1
17:34:53.919 GET https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/xpi/test/2dnzeahpy6adc/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1494ms]
17:34:53.865 "installing from /xpi/test/2dnzeahpy6adc/" ide-min.js:1
17:34:54.863 "request is running" ide-min.js:1
17:34:56.308 Očakávaná deklarácia, ale bolo nájdené '['.  Preskočené na ďalšiu deklaráciu. latest
17:34:56.309 "Add-on installed" ide-min.js:1
17:34:56.326 Chyba pri spracovaní hodnoty pre 'opacity'.  Deklarácia vynechaná. latest
17:35:00.337 Chyba pri spracovaní hodnoty pre 'top'.  Deklarácia vynechaná.
```

Comment: Is you log statement in a window context? if not, console function is not avaliable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the logging level, which by default is `error`, either globally or for specific extensions.

See the [related documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/console.html).

Comment: Hi, finally I resolved it after few days of googling.
I looked at wrong console -the right one appears after CTRL+SHIFT+J :-)